# Solve for $x$, $1-\cos(\pi+x)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi+x}{2}\right)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck with my school assignment, I cannot figure out a way to solve this for $x$.

> $$ 1- \cos(\pi+x)+ \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi+x}{2}\right) =0. $$

Any help would be appreciated!

$\cos(\pi+x)$ equals $\cos(x)$, but I have no idea what to do then.

Comment: It's $\cos (\pi+x) = -\cos x$, actually. Also, $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + y\right) = \cos y$. Then you get an equation with $\cos x$ and $\cos \frac{x}{2}$. Now use the double-angle formula.

Comment: Could you show me the double-angle formula? English isn't my first language so I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: @Kenn [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=double+angle+formula) is your friend.

Comment: But If I use double-angle formula I will get -cos^2(x/2)+sin^2(x/2)+cos(x/2)=0

What should I do next?

Comment: Use the version that says $\cos 2t=2\cos^2 t-1$. You will end up with a quadratic equation in $\cos(x/2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \dfrac{x+\pi}{2}$,
or $x = 2y-\pi$.

Your equation becomes
$1-\cos(2y)+\sin(y) = 0$
or
$1=\cos(2y)-\sin(y)$.

Since
$\cos(2y) = 1-2\sin^2(y)$,
this becomes
$$1
=(1-2\sin^2(y))-\sin(y)
=1-2\sin^2(y)-\sin(y)
$$
or
$$2\sin^2(y)+\sin(y)
=0
$$

One solution to this is
$\sin(y) = 0$.
You can determine the values of $y$
which satisfy this 
and,
from these,
get
$x = 2y-\pi$.

If $\sin(y) \ne 0$,
you can divide by $\sin(y)$
to get
$2\sin(y)+1 = 0$
or
$\sin(y) = -\frac12$.
Then get $x$ from $y$.